# Python: Stop Auto Exiting Cmd Prompt

Tags: python, cmd, notepad++, command-prompt

So I just started learning Python and just now set up my Notepad++ to run it via cmd prompt. Is there a simple way to stop my cmd prompt from auto-exiting when I run a simple program? Do I need to ask for input every time or something or is there an easier way?

I tried `raw_input('Press Enter to exit')` but no luck.

Here's the program my introduction to python book started me with http://pastebin.com/ZVJrUzZZ

If it makes any difference I'm running it straight to python.exe in python version 3.2

Comment: Could be you're using Python 3, in which case you want `input(...)` rather than `raw_input(...)`.

Comment: I think the confusion arose because you said in the question you were using Python 2.3, but in fact if you are using the latest version it's 3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea.  You would need to put something like `raw_input()` somewhere before the script exits.

---

If this is python 3, use `input` instead of `raw_input`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(approximate_size(1000000000000, False))
    print (approximate_size(1000000000000))

input('Press Enter to exit')
```

Comment: That's strange. I do, I think it says "raw input is not defined" it's hard to read when it's exiting so quickly. I updated my question with my program

Comment: Yeah since i'm running the latest version of Python it's input. That was what I was missing. Thanks, will accept answer in 7min!

Answer (score 3):

What I personally like to do is have the Python script just run to completion without asking for input, then write a batch file (Windows) or shell script (Linux/UNIX) to do the "press any key" thing. That way when I run the script from the command line it doesn't needlessly prompt me for input.

You could write a batch file like this:

```
python.exe %*
pause
```

Save it as `pypause.bat` and tell Notepad++ to run your Python scripts via this batch file instead of through `python.exe`.